# Ruby on Rails module require issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm divin to the Rails 3 via some tutorials.
I found usefull the lynda.com/Kevin Skoglund's Rails 3 Essential training.
Close to the end of the course I run into a problem what I can't solve and no reference found on the net (or lynda's site).

There is a position_mover (similar to act_as_list, but simpler) module what I must include to the model's to use.
But I'm getting errors. 
This one:

```
LoadError in SubjectsController#index

no such file to load -- lib/position_mover
Rails.root: C:/Programozas/work/simple_cms

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/subject.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:13:in `list'
app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:8:in `index'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
lib/position_mover
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

I have access to the example files also. I tried to hard copy the whole app, than modify the gems versions to be correct and I get the same error. 
The app runs perfectly untill I try to access a model, where the require presented.

A model:

```
require 'lib/position_mover'
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

include PositionMover

has_many :pages
...
end
```

I'm sure this is a kind of mega easy thing what I can't recognise. Please help to identify the problem! 
Yours,
Kael

Comment: What if you remove the `lib/` part? If the gem is in your Gemfile it is not even necessary to require it.

Comment: What mischa said, plus requireing stuff in a model is just bad. Keep it to initializers, or at least within the config/ directory. Also: if the app tells you the file does not exist, then the file does not exist. Read the fine manual.

Comment: Mischa: tx dude, I love you. Your reply solved the problem. I know, pay forvard, but I can't up your answer so thank you.

Comment: @mischa you could add your answer as an answer and @kael can check it as the right one so you both win.

Comment: @Tim, OK, I'll add it. @Kael, added my comment as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you remove the `lib/` part? If the gem is in your Gemfile it is not even necessary to require it.